# How to ensure a callback will fire when all task done by TPL

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

tell me how to write code as a result a callback function will be call to inform me that all task like task1,task2,task3 has been completed. thanks

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper way to use .ContinueWith for Tasks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904821/proper-way-to-use-continuewith-for-tasks)

Comment: @Igor are you trying to say that i should use `ContinueWith()`  ? basically i want to fire multiple function at a time but i need some callback function which fire when all function execution is completed just let me know job done.

Comment: That is exactly what `ContinueWith` is for.

Comment: i have 3 different instance of task then how could i use one ContinueWith for all 3 task instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Task.ContinueWith` with `Task.WhenAll` or you can use `Task.WaitAll` with code to run following the call to WaitAll.

```
var executingTask = Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3).ContinueWith((antecedent) =>{/*your code*/});
```

See [Task.ContinueWith documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696(v=vs.110).aspx) for additional details.

**OR**

```
// WaitAll blocks until all tasks are complete
Task.WaitAll(task1, task2, task3);
/*your code on the following lines(s) which will run after task1,task2,task3 are complete*/
```

Comment: what is antecedent ?

Comment: @MonojitSarkar - `antecedent`  - `a thing or event that existed before or logically precedes another`. You get the completed task as argument that represented the execution of `task1`, `task2`, `task3`.

Comment: very sorry still not clear the usage of antecedent. can u explain it another way?

Comment: @MonojitSarkar - you get the completed task that represents the completion of the tasks passed to `Task.WhenAll`. Check out the documentation on `ContinueWith`, there is a code example that shows `Task.Factory.StartNew` that returns a `DateTime` array which is then accessed again in the `ContinueWith`.

Comment: why negative marks because i ask the question twice?